# I need a hint to sorted out this issue

Tags: flask-wtforms

I have this form:

```
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    """Registration form."""
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 64)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required(), Length(4, 4)])
    password_again = PasswordField('Password again',
                                   validators=[Required(), EqualTo('password'), Length(4, 4)])
    tc = SelectField(validators=[Required()],
            choices=[("m_", "Yes"),
            ("n", "No")])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

And I want to add secrets.randbelow(n) next to "m_"

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to add it?"* ? Do you mean just putting `("m_" + str(secrets.randbelow(5)), "Yes")`?

Comment: Have you imported the module? `import secrets`. Not sure which python version it is in, probably 3+.

Comment: now it is working your alternative but without "secrets" in str(randbelow(5)) thank you!